# Getting jBoss not found Error

Tags: java, jboss

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JBoss
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JBoss
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Could anyone please give me an idea of what is happening? I searched, but couldnot find an effective answer. My jboss version is 4.0.5. Eclipse Indigo and java 6

I was trying to install a new server into eclipse and then when i tried to start it I got this error. My Eclipse and code was in use for so long and did not have any issues. I have currently no projects put in my server. I just tried starting it and got this error. Am I missing any configurations?

Comment: Thats nice error you have there! When does it occured? While you try tu run your project from eclipse?

Comment: interesting... can you also paste the code?

Comment: @sree very generic description. please provide the code where it throws the exception so as to help you!

Comment: Although I am not aware of any class named JBoss.. referring this could help you - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to quote my server VM arguments. just missed to put the VM arguments in double quotes and this happened.